# Fetching a blob video and submitting it along a html from

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm creating a feedback form, where the user can record their screen about an error or idea.
I made this using getDisplayMedia and mediarecorder which is then saved into a webm blob url.

Initially, we gave the user a download file of that recording and the user had to manually put it into file input, but I was wondering if it's possible to fetch that video from the blob url and submit along the form without user having to download the file or does this pose a security issue?

This has to work only on Mozilla and Chrome and if there's vanilla JS solution to this, it would be appreciated.

So, right now I have a working blob uri that is passed to the form as url parameter and now i need to get that blob video and attach it to the form so I can send it as an attachment in an email
(value $(Q:attachment) is the uri parameter that gets passed)

```html
  var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'video/webm'
  });
  
  var attachment = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```html
<form name="feedbackform" action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="video_attachment_url" id="video_attachment_url" value="$(Q:attachment)">

 <input type="submit" value="Send">
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="window.close();">

 </form>
```

Comment: what you have done ? where's your code ?

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear. I've created a blob url which is passed to the form as url parameter, so what's missing is the part where I fetch the video